# Warning/Error in Admin Panel while developing theme

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin

I am developing a theme for my website. As soon as I activated the theme, the following errors/warnings shows up on the top of the admin panel on every page.

```
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method WPEditorAdmin::removeDefaultEditorMenus() should not be called statically in C:\Users\...\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 406

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method WPEditorAdmin::buildAdminMenu() should not be called statically in C:\Users\...\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 406

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method WPEditorAdmin::addThemesPage() should not be called statically in C:\Users\...\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 406

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method WPEditorAdmin::editorStylesheetAndScripts() should not be called statically in C:\Users\...\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 406
```

I am wondering how do I solve these errors and not have this happen anymore?
Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your code where you're using add_action or add_filter in relation to `removeDefaultEditorMenus`? e.g., `add_action('SOME_HOOK', array($SOME_OBJ, 'removeDefaultEditorMenus'));`

Answer (score 5):

So you have your code in a class, let's say it looks like this...

```
<?php
class WPSE82245
{
    public function action_init()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Now you try to hook it into something...

```
add_action('init', 'array('WPSE82245', 'action_init'));
```

What happens is when the `init` hook fires, WordPress tries to call your method. It would similar to if you just wrote this...

```
WPSE82245::action_init();
```

But PHP doesn't like that because you haven't declare you method `static`, that is, able to be used without an instance of its container class (like the example directly above).

This makes sense, what if you used `$this` in your method? Calling it statically would cause a runtime error saying that `$this` was being used outside an object context.

You can remove the errors by declaring your method static...

```
<?php
class WPSE82245
{
    public static function action_init()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Or using an instance of your class as the first element of the array the callable argument of `add_action`.

```
<?php
class WPSE82245
{
    public function action_init()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

$cls = new WPSE82245();
add_action('init', array($cls, 'action_init'));
```

The above is just an example there are [many](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70060/6035) different [ways](http://wptip.me/classes-in-wordpress-plugins-themes) to instantiate a class in a WordPress theme/plugin.

Comment: Where would this be? I don't get it because this started with a blank wordpress theme.

Comment: that you developed? Or that you go from somewhere? Without seeing its code, it could be anywhere, but most likely in `functions.php`.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have anything related to wordpress in the functions.php

Comment: Edited with screenshot

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down @chrisguitarguy. Saved me some time vs just turning off debug mode :D. 
It was happening with me while creating a menu page inside of a class, i had to declare the add_menu_page callable function as being static.