# calling a function from a class in your template

Tags: php, themes, hooks, oop

ok, so I have created a plugin in Wordpress. I want to be able to use some values I have created in a function within my template but I just don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I have created my plugin within a class the structure is:

```
class foo_class {

    public  $foo;

    public function __construct() {   

         $this->foo = 'hello';

    } 

    public function wordpress_test() {
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}

$foo_class = new foo_class ();
```

Soooooo my thinking is within a theme file I should just be able to go...

```
var_dump($foo_class->wordpress_test());
```

but this seems to just stop loading the page when I hit the var_dump call. Am I hooking into this wrong?

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: yes, I get 'call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wordpress_test' not found or invalid function name in...'

Comment: Also instantiate the object in your template instead.

Comment: what happens if you add `global $foo_class;` before the `var_dump`?

Comment: no, instantiating the object in the template is probably not what you want to do, your class won't exist before the `template_redirect` action. your code works as-is, as long as the instance is [within scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Create a new instance in the theme file from the class of the plugin. `$foo_class = new foo_class(); var_dump($foo_class->wordpress_test());` Maybe also check  if the class is exists. Do you have debug mode active?

Comment: Looking at your question again. If your plugin is one single class then you must have to instantiate the object from the plugin file. At least the functionality like option pages, version checks should be run from the plugin file. But still using global should be avoided.

Comment: [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70055/best-way-to-initiate-a-class-in-a-wp-plugin) is good reading on instantiating a class in a plugin.