# Will simple function names in a class structure conflict with other plugins?

Tags: php, plugin-development

I implement a `class` structure in my plugin, for example:

```
class Ethans_Plugin {
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin' ), 10, 1 );
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'footer' ), 10, 1 );
    }

    public function admin() {
        # code here...
    }

    public function footer() {
        # code here...
    }
}
```

When I define functions with generic names such as `admin` or `footer` will this conflict with any other function that have the same names? Or, since they are within a class, these function names will make them unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method name is not callable without an instance of the class, so no, it cannot conflict with the same method names from other classes, because the class names, including the namespace, must be unique.

Btw: [Never register callbacks in a constructor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166532/73).

Answer (score -2):

yes.  they could conflict.  Always create your namespace.  What if another ethan is thinking the exact same thing as you?  MIND BLOWN!

Comment: Could you provide an example of namespacing, maybe using his code?

Comment: actually they can't conflict. to conflict a different plugin will need to use the same class name, so whatever conflit that ther might be will be on a different level