# Instantiating classes in constructor vs in a method

Tags: plugins, php, oop

I'm writing a plugin, and for the most part I'm following the [plugin boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/) with the addition of autoloading and namespacing.

When running the main class, where you include methods to run in the constructor

```
function run_plugin_name() {
    $plugin = new Plugin_Name();
    $plugin->run();
}
run_plugin_name();
```

in the `Plugin_Name` class we have

```
class Plugin_Name {

    protected $loader;

    protected $plugin_name;

    protected $version;

    public function __construct() {
        if ( defined( 'PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION' ) ) {
            $this->version = PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION;
        } else {
            $this->version = '1.0.0';
        }
        $this->plugin_name = 'plugin-name';
        $this->load_dependencies();
        $this->set_locale();
        $this->define_admin_hooks();
        $this->define_public_hooks();
    }
}
```

I am wondering what is the best practice, and if there is any benefit if I define the objects that will be used in the `add_action` / `add_filter` methods inside the constructor like

```
public function __construct() {
    if ( defined( 'PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION' ) ) {
      $this->version = PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION;
    } else {
      $this->version = '1.0.0';
    }
    $this->plugin_name = 'plugin-name';

    $this->admin = new Admin( $this->plugin_name, $this->version );

    $this->load_dependencies();
    $this->set_locale();
    $this->define_admin_hooks();
    $this->define_public_hooks();
}
```

and then use this inside, say `define_admin_hooks()` method

```
private function define_admin_hooks() {
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $this->admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $this->admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

Or should I do it like it's done in the plugin boilerplate

```
private function define_admin_hooks() {
    $plugin_admin = new Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

The reason I'm asking is because I have several methods where I add my actions and filters, based on the plugin functionality, and there are some classes that I'm using in both methods. So it seems better to have them in the constructor and then just use them in the methods.

That way I'm not breaking the DRY principle.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You should read this popular Q/A - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70055/best-way-to-initiate-a-class-in-a-wp-plugin

Comment: Yeah, that did not really answer my question. Plus I'm avoiding singletons in favor of dependency injections.

Comment: However a empty constructor is not only in the context of Singletons, the benefit is for unit testing.