# OOP development and hooks

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, oop

I'm currently working on writing my first OOP Plugin for Wordpress.

To help out a little bit with structure I looked for, and found, [a boiler plate](https://github.com/davilera/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate-with-PSR-4) that sets up the basics for me.

In `Main.php` there's a method that loads JS and CSS assets for admin:

```
/**
 * Register all of the hooks related to the admin area functionality
 * of the plugin.
 *
 * @since    0.1.0
 * @access   private
 */
private function define_admin_hooks() {

  $plugin_admin = new Admin\Controller( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version(), $this->get_plugin_path() );

  $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
  $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );

}
```

So far, so good.
But as my plugin grows in complexity, it feels like this method is gonna get unwieldy with alot of hooks.

Here's an example with a CPT setup and a setting page added

```
/**
 * Register all of the hooks related to the admin area functionality
 * of the plugin.
 *
 * @since    0.1.0
 * @access   private
 */
private function define_admin_hooks() {

  $plugin_admin = new Admin\Controller( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version(), $this->get_plugin_path() );

  $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
  $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );


  $interactWithVimeo = new Admin\InteractWithVimeo();
  $this->loader->add_action ( 'admin_init', $interactWithVimeo, 'setCredentials');


  $cpt = new Admin\CustomPostType();

  // Create the custom post type
  $this->loader->add_action ( 'init', $cpt, 'create_post_type' );

  // Remove post row actions
  $this->loader->add_filter ( 'post_row_actions', $cpt, 'remove_row_actions', 10, 2 );



  $settingsPage = new Admin\SettingsPage();

  // Add the settings page to CPT menu
  $this->loader->add_action ( 'admin_menu', $settingsPage, 'add_settings_page' );
}
```

At this point I'm wondering if it would be better to simply setup the different classes to load their own hooks within themselves to avoid the clutter in `Main.php`

Such as

```
/**
 * Register all of the hooks related to the admin area functionality
 * of the plugin.
 *
 * @since    0.1.0
 * @access   private
 */
private function define_admin_hooks() {

  $myExensiveClassWithAlotOfMethods = new Admin\MyExensiveClassWithAlotOfMethods();
  $this->loader->add_action ( 'admin_init', $myExensiveClassWithAlotOfMethods, 'init' );

}
```

And the init method in the class then contains all the hooks that the class needs.

Is this a bad idea? There seems to be different ways to do it of course. I'm just curious which approach seems to be inline with the boiler plate.

Comment: I flagged this question as off topic and think you'll better be fit to post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). As to what is "inline with the boiler plate" - no idea, you could ask via an issue. I use a similar boilerplate, but with static classes for the actions - [makes every `add_action` a one-liner](https://pastebin.com/CbrnPME7) (and should be better for memory). But will switch to a more "dependancy injection" style soon

Comment: IMHO, a `class` should only initialize its own hooks, and if the class instantiates other classes, let the classes initialize their own hooks. There are exceptions, but that depend on your code.

Comment: @SallyCJ Would you be able to supply a condensed example of what you mean?

Comment: Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/tJKC6dDG) simplified example. But of course that doesn't use the boilerplate in question. Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks alot! Seems to be how I imagine it, but in my case I would not use the contructor, but a method that serves as initiator.

Comment: Hooks initiated with `$this` are a [PITA to remove](https://inpsyde.com/en/remove-wordpress-hooks/), just keep that in mind

Comment: @kero Would you be able to post the content of Shortcode\News or any of the other so I can try and wrap my head about how this works? :)

Comment: Here's a brilliant old thread, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70055/best-way-to-initiate-a-class-in-a-wp-plugin, and answer, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166532/144392, regarding initializing classes. I don't know if this helps you with the boiler plate, but at least I learned a lot when reading that thread and answers to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj) raises a good point in [their comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/315986/oop-development-and-hooks?noredirect=1#comment467296_315986) that it is probably better to have each class initialize its own actions and filters.

I've been working with the same boiler plate for some time now and [created my own version of this boiler plate on GitHub](https://github.com/MNKYlab/wordpress-demoplugin/).

In that version I have a `Back\Hooks` and a `General\Hooks`, both Singletons and getting passed the `Loader`. This is how the `General\Hooks` looks in one project

```
<?php

namespace ACME\General;

class Hooks
{
        protected static $instance;
        protected $loader;

        public static function getInstance($loader)
        {
                if (self::$instance === null) {
                        self::$instance = new self($loader);
                }
                return self::$instance;
        }

        protected function __construct($loader)
        {
                $this->loader = $loader;
        }

        public function run()
        {
                $this->addActions();
                $this->addFilters();
        }

        protected function addActions()
        {
                AdvancedCustomFields\Options::add($this->loader);
                $this->loader->addAction('init', Shortcode\News::class, 'init');
                $this->loader->addAction('init', Shortcode\Courses::class, 'init');
                $this->loader->addAction('wp_footer', WooCommerce\Foo::class, 'print_modal');
                // and many more
        }

        protected function addFilters()
        {
                $this->loader->addFilter('the_content', Bar\Baz::class, 'filter_the_content', 999);
                // and many more
        }
}
```

Now in the case of `AdvancedCustomFields\Options` I already pass the loader and do the initialization inside that class, doing that for all the other cases would probably be much cleaner.

`General\Shortcode\News` looks like this

```
<?php

namespace ACME\General\Shortcode;

class News
{
    public static function init()
    {
        add_shortcode('acme_news', [__CLASS__, 'render']);
    }

    public static function render($raw_atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
    {
        $raw_atts = array_change_key_case((array)$raw_atts, CASE_LOWER);
        $atts = shortcode_atts([
            'size' => 'large',
            'amount' => '4',
            'offset' => '0',
            'exclude' => '',
        ], $raw_atts, $tag);

        /* filter $atts */
        $atts['amount'] = intval($atts['amount']);
        $atts['offset'] = intval($atts['offset']);

        /* get result */
        $result = '';
        // actual code, doing WP_Query, etc.
        // never directly outputted but only saved in $result

        return $result;
}
```