# When developing WordPress plugin, is it a good idea to create my class object by hooking to existing class constructor?

Tags: customization, oop

I want to create my object when another object is made.
Is it a good idea to create my object by hooking to existing class constructor?

for example if the main class is

```
class WordPress_Class {
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'some_action', array( $this, 'some_WP_Class_Method' ) );

    return true;
}
```

Then can I use 'some_action' to create my object:

```
my_object = new My_Class();
```

and use it on the same page that WordPress_Class object is used?

Comment: It depends on the context. Can you give an actual example do what you’re trying to do?

Comment: You might find this interesting and relevant, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70055/best-way-to-initiate-a-class-in-a-wp-plugin