# Hooking Into Widget Output Loop

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar

When wordpress sidebar outputs any particular `registered sidebar` it loop through all widgets that assigned through it and outputs it (i guess). Is is possible to hook into the loop and add some content, say **I want to add a ad code every three widgets**.

**What I have tried?** Unable to find any leads. Tried to search on wordpress source code but not sure what to search. searching `widget` or `widget loop` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook into `'dynamic_sidebar'` and count how often it is called.

You get the current active sidebar with `key( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] )`.

```
add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar', 'wpse_96681_hr' );

function wpse_96681_hr( $widget )
{
    static $counter = 0;

    // right sidebar in Twenty Ten. Adjust to your needs.
    if ( 'primary-widget-area' !== key( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] ) )
        return;

    if ( 0 !== $counter && 0 === $counter % 3 )
        print '<hr>';

    $counter += 1;
}
```

Comment: `dynamic_sidebar`, got it!

Comment: I tested it. :) It works but the first `<hr>` is placed right after the second widget not the third. After that it skips three then adds a line.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I made an important update. Could you test it again please? :)

Comment: The update works but adds an `<hr>` at the very top then adds a line after every third item.

Comment: That last edit did it. Perfection.

Comment: Works! But how do i only apply it on a specific side bar. I am trying with `is_active_sidebar()`. Doesn't seem to work. It still showing the `<hr>` on all widget area.

Comment: @Sisir See my update. Works in Twenty Ten now only in the primary sidebar.

Comment: I don't see how `key( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] )` will get the current active sidebar. For me, it simply returns the first sidebar from the `wp_regsitered_sidebars` array.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as toscho's but I made a class.

```
class SideBar_Inserter {
  static $count = 0;

  function __construct() {
    add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar', array($this,'insert_into_sidebar') );
  }

  function insert_into_sidebar($s) {
    if (static::$count !== 0 && static::$count%3 === 0) {
      echo static::$count;
    }
    static::$count++;
  }
}
$sidebar_inserter = new SideBar_Inserter;
```

This is tested. It works.

Comment: An [anonymous object](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57088/73)? Why?

Comment: Just to kick the constructor. I should have done `$sidebar_inserter = new SideBar_Inserter;` or made a static class but I am not fond of those.