# looping widgets to organize bootstrap grids

Tags: widgets, columns, twitter-bootstrap

Using twitter bootsrap I want to grid my widgets if in the same position more widgets are present what I mean: having a registered widget

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Footer Top', 'roots'),
    'id' => 'footer-top',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="footer_teaser %1$s %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

how would I count and loop all widgets in columns? Lets say I have theoretically 3(this would be variable) widgets in a given position than I would split 12/3(or with another counted) which would give me with the example above `footer_teaser col-sm-4 col-md-4`

than the expected result would generate something like

```
<div class="footer_teaser col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <h3>About us</h3>
                    <p>Fugiat dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, mauesris condime ntum nibh, ut fermentum mas justo sitters.</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 3 Athens street</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (+30) 265-9987</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-print"></i> (+30) 9854-7855</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> hello@domain.de</p>
</div>
```

So far what I found  for counting the widgets

```
function count_sidebar_widgets($sidebar_id, $echo = true) {
    $the_sidebars = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
    if (!isset($the_sidebars[$sidebar_id]))
        return __('Invalid sidebar ID');
    if ($echo)
        return 12 / count($the_sidebars[$sidebar_id]);
    else
        return count($the_sidebars[$sidebar_id]);
}
```

than on generation I do

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Footer Top', 'roots'),
    'id' => 'footer-top',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="footer_teaser col-lg-'.count_sidebar_widgets('footer-top').'">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

but I'm not satisfied with it

Answer (score 1):

Would each of the columns have the same corresponding bootstrap classes (`col-sm-4 col-md-4`)?  If so, you can just add those classes to the `<div>` referenced in `before_widget`, like:

```
   register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Footer Top', 'roots'),
    'id' => 'footer-top',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="footer_teaser %1$s %2$s col-sm-4 col-md-4">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
   ));
```

But I may have misunderstood what you're going for.  If you need a different class in each widget, might be simplest to just register two different widget areas with different classes applied.

Comment: look at my update. So to columns would be dynamically generated could have different grid classes

Comment: Ah, it's a good idea, really.  I'll read through what you wrote and come up with an answer.

Comment: fefe, what is wrong with the solution you came up with?  I mean, what do you not like about the output you're getting from that?  I mean, one thing I see is that sometimes you will get non-integers when dividing -- for example, if you have 11 widgets, 12/11 = 1.09, which isn't going to match the class name of a column.  Maybe use `round()` or `floor()` on `count_sidebar_widgets()`?  But I am also not exactly sure why you'd ever want the output provided by `$echo = false`.  In that case, if you had 11 widgets, each would be `col-lg-11`, right?

Comment: yepp you are right but what is if I want to create a new row if the actual row is overloaded?

Comment: What's the row class name?  It seems like you need to create another variable, maybe `$i` that increments each time a widget is added.  When `$i == (12/count_sidebar_widgets())`, close the previous row and output a new one.  I found this related to hooking into the widgets loop: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96681/hooking-into-widget-output-loop  You'd need to pass the result of `(12/count_sidebar_widgets())` to the loop function as the number of widgets per row.  When I have a moment, I'll revise my answer.