# Stop parsing shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

I'd like to stop parsing shortcodes in `the_content` but I'm struggling to find what the correct filter would be. This didn't work:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 40 );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'run_shortcode', 40 );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop', 40 );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'autoembed', 40 );
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment', 40 );
```

This worked (but also disabled all other useful filters):

```
remove_all_filters( 'the_content', 40 );
```

So, I'd like to disable `autoembed` and `do_shortcode` and let WordPress display them as plain text. Would it be possible? I'm using `wp` hook in main plugin's PHP file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is calling `remove_filter` with the *same priority* as the hook was added:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
```

Some plugins change this filter’s priority, so you could clear the global list of registered shortcodes temporary:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'toggle_shortcodes', -1 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'toggle_shortcodes', PHP_INT_MAX );

function toggle_shortcodes( $content )
{
    static $original_shortcodes = array();

    if ( empty ( $original_shortcodes ) )
    {
        $original_shortcodes = $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags'];
        $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags'] = array();
    }
    else
    {
        $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags'] = $original_shortcodes;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But is this the only way to do that? Why not just `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 40 );`?

Comment: @Paul 40 cannot work, because the priority is an array key. There is no entry for that filter at position 40, so the removal must fail.

Comment: I thought that it works like: `add_filter( 'the_content', 'some_function', 10);` and `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'some_shortcode', 11);`. Expected result: `some_function()` will not be added. Here they mention `int` for priority: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter so I'm a bit confused. It would be great if you could update your answer with a few more words of explanation that an average user would understand :) It works so this question is answered but I still wonder why my attempts failed.

Comment: @Paul For an explanation of the structure of the global filter list, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57088/73). You can see the priority as key there (5, 12, 20, 1000).