# Overwrite or Replace code in WP_Footer

Tags: plugins, actions, footer, scripts

I have a some code being dynamically added into my Footer via `add_action('wp_footer' ...)`. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to remove it using conventional methods, I've looked at the following question and tried to use the solutions there:

[remove_action or remove_filter with external classes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes)

But had no luck with any of the answers so now I'm looking for *Alternatives*. Is there a way to actually to run some kind of `preg_replace` on the contents of `wp_footer()`? Are there any other ways to remove things in `wp_footer` without using `remove_action()`?

**More Information:**

The plugin has an [output file](http://pastebin.com/QSW5sC6a). On *line 697* is where the action actually gets added:

`add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'add_inline_styles'));`

The actual function is defined on *line 1743*

I wasn't sure whether to reference `RevOperations::` or `RevSliderFront::` - Here's the [initial setup file](http://pastebin.com/mSucy6cS) in the root of the plugin folder.

Comment: *"Are there any other ways to remove things in wp_footer without using remove_action()?"* dom manipulation can work, but if the action that prints stuff on footer is added, there should be a way to remove it, and that is fair better. Show us the code that add the action and tell us where it is placed, an I bet someone can find a way to remove it...

Comment: @G.M. Well the problem is that it's premium plugin code, and doing so would probably steer the question to "Off-Topic" so I wanted to make it more WP Friendly. The main problem is that when adding it to footer it references `$this` and I've tried at least 50 combinations of classes and functions to figure out how to remove it (referencing the linked question above) but couldn't. I'll add in some code detail on Monday though.

Comment: @G.M. added some more info along with some pastebins. I kind of took a shotgun approach to my testing but none of it seemed to stick. http://pastebin.com/ns6Byc1J

Comment: What's the instance of the `RevSliderOutput` class? We must also remember that to remove an action we must use the same priority used when it was added.

Comment: @birgire in the initial setup file linked above it gets called a few times, *line 84, 146, 149, and 156*. 90% of gets thrown into an `$output` variable. . It also creates an instance in the output file linked above on *line 80*

Comment: It looks like the instance isn't available to us. One (long route!) would be to redefine the `rev_slider` shortcode and start from there, doing some code rewrites. A possible "hacky" shortcut might be to check the data in `$GLOBALS['wp_filter']['wp_footer']` and see if you can identify it there so you could remove it before the `wp_footer` hook is activated.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like there is no easy way to remove it which is pretty unfortunate and my best bet is probably @aifrim answer. Thanks for looking into it though!

Comment: Sometimes contacting the plugin author can work wonders ;-)

Comment: @birgire I did, but their support aren't developers so I keep getting generic responses. They finally told me to just comment out the line in the plugin file to solve the problem since I know where it is =/

Comment: I see, who doesn't love manual labor ;-) PS: It would be interesting to see the relevant `print_r( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['wp_footer'][10] );` part, to see the cryptic function callback for this case.

Comment: @birgire Yeah I tried to print globals at one point to figure out what the global instance for the plugin was nothing seemed obvious (reference in admin_head and enqueue scripts but that's it). Using your print_r() though I get nothing, if I remove the `[10]` I get 2 things: `wp_print_footer_scripts` at 20 and `wp_admin_bar_render` at 100

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/140989/35541). Using the function there, you can remove the action using `add_action( 'wp_footer', function() { remove_object_filter( 'wp_footer', 'RevSliderOutput', 'add_inline_styles', 10 ); }, 0);`

Comment: @G.M. 10/10 That worked. /u/birgire and yourself mentioned the 10 priority and if I use anything other than 10 in the code you posted stops working. Where are you guys finding the 10 priority? When the action is being added, it gets added at no priority (Line 697). Thanks btw!!

Comment: When an hook is added with no priority WordPress uses the default one, that is 10. [Source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/809baf442b0bd4aaedbbc06de8d6d14408a73d7b/wp-includes/plugin.php#L82)

Comment: You should try to print it from the `wp_footer` hook to see it. Good to hear you solved it with the great function (+1) from @G.M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ruled out `remove_action` there is only one way you can do it. And you've guessed it: `preg_repalce`, `substr` mixture but with a little help and [**PHP DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_start_footer_ob', 1);
function my_start_footer_ob() {
    ob_start("my_end_footer_ob_callback");
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'my_end_footer_ob', 1000);
function my_end_footer_ob() {
    ob_end_flush();
}

function my_end_footer_ob_callback($buffer) {
    // remove what you need from he buffer

    return $buffer;
}
```

Within `my_end_footer_ob_callback` you edit the `$buffer` to your needs. The `$buffer` parameters should have all the contents of the footer after all actions and filters have been call to action. If it does not simply edit `1000` to a [**bigger number**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer#Set_priority_of_your_action) so that `my_end_footer_ob` is called last.

Now, I do not know what **HTML** contents that action produces but you can use `pre_replace` or a sequence of `substr`s to remove it.

If you want to use **PHP DOM** do it like this:

```
function my_end_footer_ob_callback($buffer) {
    // remove what you need from he buffer

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($buffer);

    $docElem = $doc->getElementById("theID");

    if($docElem !== NULL) // if it exists
        $docElem->parentNode->removeChild($docElem);

    return $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->firstChild->nodeValue;
}
```

Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: `$doc->saveHTML()` seems to create a new document root in my footer. `<!DOCTYPE html ... <html>...<head>...etc.` But I'll play around with this and see if I can get it to work with `preg_replace()`

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, ups, my bad: here you go. An edit.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but for ob_start() to catch everything I would have to run this before any plugins or functions run. I tried to add it ont the action `muplugins_loaded` but still had no luck with the buffer. I ran a few simple tests which I've added in a pastebin if you would like to try them. http://pastebin.com/Duxjrsz5  -- Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Don't activate the functions in that hook. They have hooks of their own. I have made 1 modification to the code. I gave priority 1 to the ob_start() function. Read about the hooks I use and you will see that I ob_start() when wp_footer is initialized and ob_flush at the end of the rendering.

Comment: unfortunately it remove everything in wp_footer, all my footer scripts disappear when using this method but +1 for effort. even if I try to store and echo the end_flush I get nothing from it.

Comment: Plugged in my preg_replace and it returned the `$buffer` and it worked like a charm. So I mean, answer solved for the most part, if you have revisions of your answer I can keep testing it so Future Readers have working code to go off of.

Comment: Since you just want to remove the `<div class="revsliderstyles">...</div>` output just add the preg_replace so I can make the proper adjustments.