# remove filter added by plugin with anonymous function

Tags: plugins, filters

Just for testing, I created a plugin with this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , function( $fields ) {
unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
return $fields; } );
```

Now, I would like to remove it with functions.php file in child theme. The problem is anonymous function, so cannot just call remove_filter. Don't ask me to create a function with name, because I am working on a project, which I need to remove that filter without changing the plugin code.

I see some threads about this, but they are old, and not working. Any idea for completing this task, please?

Thanks.

Comment: From what I've been able to glean, removing anonymous functions from filter hooks is difficult. [This help thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/usage-of-anonymous-functions-in-hooks-and-filters/) suggests trying [Objects Hooks Remover](https://github.com/inpsyde/objects-hooks-remover), which I have not tested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Actions/Filters added via Anonymous Functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137688/remove-actions-filters-added-via-anonymous-functions)