How to remove a filter which calls a function with private instance
I recently encountered a problem so i needed to remove a callback from a hook which was implemented by a 3rd party plug in but the instance passed with the function was a private instance now how can i remove the callback from the hook
if(!class_exists('Test_Ad')){
    class Test_Ad{
       private function init(){
           $admin_ins = new Test_Admin($this->get_name(), $this->version());

           add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns',array($admin_ins,'mv_test_adding') );       
           add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', array($admin_ins,'populate_columns'), 10, 2 );   
       }
       public function __construct(){
           $this->init();
       }
       public function get_name(){
           return 'admin';
       }
       public function version(){
           return '1.0.0';
       }

    }
    $test = new Test_Ad();

}

If this function still works maybe give it an upvote: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/140989/7355

Thanks accessing the calback using the wp_filter object i can remove the callback.
