# Remove action added from class

Tags: filters, actions, page-template

This has been asked before and I know how to do this but im having trouble removing a specific action added by the easy columns plugin.

The action is added similar to below:

```
class EasyColumns {

    function __construct(){

         add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'add_css'), 100);
    }

    function add_css(){
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo EZC_PLUGIN_URL; ?>/css/easy-columns.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    }

}

$ez_columns = new EasyColumns();
```

Ok it should be easy enough to remove. I have tried removing it from my childtheme functions and within a page-template which should be loaded after the plugin using:

```
remove_action('wp_head', array( "EasyColumns", 'add_css' ), 100);   // also diff priorities, 1000, 1 etc
```

or

```
global $ez_columns;
remove_action('wp_head', array( $ez_columns, 'add_css' ), 100);
```

But it stays there! I've also tried hooking the remove action to wp-head, init, etc. Am i missing something here?

Ps, its not a caching issue.

Comment: Give it a priority of 101 instead of 100.

Comment: @AndrewBartel priority on remove action must match the priority it was added on.

Comment: this worked, although im not sure why remove action was not, the above was not anon. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object