# remove_action not working, even after changing priority

Tags: functions, filters, child-theme

So one of the functions in my theme is:

```
public function job_manager_job_filters_distance() {
   //Show some HTML
}
```

And somewhere else in the document lies:

```
add_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', array( $this, 'job_manager_job_filters_distance' ), 0 );
```

**I want to disable this function.**

So naturally I went to my child theme's functions.php and added *remove_action*:

```
remove_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', 'job_manager_job_filters_distance' );
```

It didn't work. Then I tried different priorities for the removal:

```
remove_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', 'job_manager_job_filters_distance', 20 );
```

Still no go. Then I tried to wrap it in a function that triggers after theme load:

```
function remove_listify_junk() {
    remove_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', 'job_manager_job_filters_distance' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_listify_junk', 999 );
```

And the function is still doing it's thing =[...

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to unhook a PHP *function* as opposed to a (class) instance method - see here:

```
array( $this, 'job_manager_job_filters_distance' )
```

...that's the *actual* callback registered to the hook. To unhook you need the same (a reference to the instance).

If you are trying to unhook from *within* the class, it's as easy as using the above. Otherwise you need a reference to the instance - look for something like the following in your code:

```
$my_class = new Name_Of_Class;
```

...then you'd run:

```
remove_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', array( $my_class, 'job_manager_job_filters_distance' ) , 0 );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. I get it now. As for your suggestion, the class is not declared within a variable, so thats a bummer. I tried doing: `$myvar = new Listify_WP_Job_Manager_Map;
class Listify_WP_Job_Manager_Map extends listify_Integration {...}` and then on functions.php 
`remove_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', array( $myvar, 'job_manager_job_filters_distance' ) , 0 );` But still it's not working. Maybe because the variable is inaccessible? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Damn, I thought that might be the case. Trouble is, running another `$x = new Y` will not point to the original instance (it's a *new* one). When you say this class is in your theme, is it in `functions.php`? If not where is it defined (loosely describe your theme architecture)

Comment: The architecture is quite complex. Listify integrates with a bunch of plugins via built-in integration files in the theme's folder -- in addition to the actual plugin files in _wp-content\plugins_. The file I was referring to is located in _wp-content\themes\listify\inc\integrations\wp-job-manager\map\class-wp-job-manager-map-template.php_. I'm sure it's very hard/nearly impossible to figure it out without access to the actual files... And maybe I can explain myself better, but I am not that familiar with OOP in PHP... So anyway I appriciate your effort =]

Comment: Well since the file is in your theme, you could just comment out the `add_action` line - otherwise try [this technique for "finding" & un-hooking anonymous instances](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57088/1685)