# Removing a Filter

Tags: hooks

I'm using 'Simply Show Hooks' plugin to spot various filters on a page.

I'm trying to remove the following filter's function (method): `UM_User_posts–>add_tab`

Here's my `remove_filter` code so far:

```
remove_filter( 'um_profile_tabs', '_____', 100);
```

How exactly would I include that function (method)?

Comment: It'a an class instance then either you use `remove_all_filters('um_profile_tabs', 100);` to remove everything on filter `um_profile_tabs`. or you loop over all filters of this hook to remove only this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see a hook callback described as `UM_User_posts–>add_tab`, you know there must be an `UM_User_posts` object somewhere. If `add_tab()` had been called statically, the callback description would be `UM_User_posts::add_tab`.

Now you need access to the same instance of the `UM_User_posts` class that the plugin is using. How to get to that instance? That's often not possible, so you have to use [an ugly workaround](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57088/73).

In *your* case however, there is a better way. The one, very important information that I'm missing in your question is: What is the plugin whose callback you want to remove? My *guess* is you are using the plugin Ultimate Members. :)

Now, when I look at the [part where the instance for `UM_User_posts` is created](https://github.com/wp-plugins/ultimate-member/blob/9bb3cb349244ac0eae0ee36098b52a1dcb38c360/um-init.php#L151), I notice two things:

1. I'm running out of polite words to describe that code. Probably my fault. :) But honestly, I would *not* run that code in production.
2. The instance is assigned to an undeclared member `user_posts` of the class `UM_API`, and the instance of *that* class is put into a global variable named `$ultimatemember`. So the instance you need in order to remove the callback is in `$GLOBALS['ultimatemember']->user_posts`.

And that leads us to the solution:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() {
    remove_filter( 
        'um_profile_tabs', 
        [ $GLOBALS['ultimatemember']->user_posts, 'add_tab' ], 
        100
    );
});
```

I haven't tested it, because I really don't want to install that anywhere, so … good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, I am trying out the Ultimate Members plugin. Are you saying the plugin code isn't good enough for production? I also gave your code a shot, but no success. :( I really appreciate your detailed explanation though!

Comment: @Richard You have to call your `remove_filter()` after the plugin has created its own instance. The plugin code in general is violating so many best practices that I wouldn't trust it one bit without reviewing every single line.

Comment: Ouch! We were hoping of using it in production. :( How would I call it after the plugin has created its own instance though?

Comment: @Richard I have modified my code to wait for the plugin load. If that still doesn't work, you have to a. dig into the plugin code for yourself, b. find a better plugin, c. write your own code for the membership functionality you need, or d. ask the plugin author for support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the name of the function that was hooked to the filter via the `add_filter()` command, as well as the priority at which it was hooked.

So, in your example, let's assume that the `add_filter()` in question looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'um_profile_tabs', array( 'UM_User_posts', 'add_tab' ), 100 );
```

Then your `remove_filter()` should be:

```
remove_filter( 'um_profile_tabs', array( 'UM_User_posts', 'add_tab' ), 100 );
```

You *do* need to match the priority of the `add_filter()` call. If there's no priority specified in the `add_filter()`, then it will default to `10`. (`remove_filter()` likewise defaults to a priority of `10`.)

### References

- [`remove_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/)
- [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

Comment: Thanks, here's what I'm seeing: filter: um_profile_tabs

Priority: 100
UM_User_posts–>add_tab

Comment: I tried your code example and it did not work, even though the priority matched.

Comment: There _must_ be an `UM_User_posts` object. Your code is treating the method as a `static` method which is clearly not in use here.

Comment: @fuxia How would I remove the method then?