# How to change the order (priority) of registered filters (or actions) (e.g. for the_content)?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions, api, the-content

Is there any way to change the order of filters for e.g. the_content before they are applied? What I currently have is the following ideas:

```
/**
 * Print all filters for some hook.
 */
function print_filters_for( $hook = '' ) {
    global $wp_filter;
    if( empty( $hook ) || !isset( $wp_filter[$hook] ) )
        return;

    print '<pre>';
    print_r( $wp_filter[$hook] );
    print '</pre>';
}

add_action('template_redirect','print_filters');

function print_filters() {
    print_r(print_filters_for('the_content'));die;
}
```

This gives me the filters, but I can not think of any comfortable way to change their priorities.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter_priority_reorder', 0 );

function my_content_filter_priority_reorder($the_content) {
    // reorder filter priorities
    return $the_content;
}
```

Has anybody already had this problem and knows how to possibly change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the existing callback and priority you can just remove the filters and then add again at a different priority:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies', 20 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies', 30 );

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'capital_P_dangit', 11 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'capital_P_dangit', 20 );
```

Comment: That seems basically the correct way to do it, congrats on 10K reputation  
Do you know a method to extract a filters registered plain names such you can proceed with reordering them?

Comment: You'll need to print them out the way you have in your question. The tricky part  is that hooked functions won't all just be a simple function name. Hooks are [callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and can require a reference to other objects to remove. See [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57088/39152) old question and answer on findind and removing hooks.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change the priority of the plain function, using `remove_filter()` => `add_filter()` pattern is okay. But if you try to change it for method callback, it might be a pain since you need to somehow get an object of this method. And in a lot of cases, it's impossible.

I mean cases when the filter is created this way:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'change_content' ) );
```

For such cases, it's better to change it manually by updating the `$wp_filter` variable.

Here is a function for it:

```
  /**
   * Changes the filter priority.
   *
   * @param string $hook_name
   * @param string $function_name Either function or method name
   * @param int $new_priority
   *
   * @return bool If it's changed correctly or not.
   */
   function change_filter_priority( $hook_name, $function_name, $new_priority ) {
    global $wp_filter;

    if ( empty( $wp_filter[ $hook_name ] ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $hook = $wp_filter[ $hook_name ];

    foreach ( $hook->callbacks as $priority => $callbacks ) {
        foreach ( $callbacks as $callback_id => $callback ) {
            $current_function = $callback['function'];
            if ( is_array( $current_function ) ) { // case it's a function in the class.
                $current_function = $current_function[1];
            }

            if ( $function_name === $current_function ) {
                if ( $new_priority != $priority ) {
                    $priority_existed = isset( $hook->callbacks[ $new_priority ] );
                    $hook->callbacks[ $new_priority ][ $callback_id ] = $hook->callbacks[ $priority ][ $callback_id ];
                    unset( $hook->callbacks[ $priority ][ $callback_id ] );
                    if ( ! $priority_existed ) {
                        ksort( $hook->callbacks, SORT_NUMERIC );
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage example:

```
class My_Class {
  public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'change_content' ), 10 );
  }

  public function change_content() {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}

new My_Class();

change_filter_priority( 'the_content', 'change_content', 11 );
```