# Remove an action from an external Class

Tags: actions, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm trying to do something similar to this question here: [remove_action or remove_filter with external classes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes)

I'm trying to remove the

> `<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.0.3 - http;//yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->`

message from the plugin.

And before you yell at me about how this may be unethical the author says it's okay to do here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-how-to-remove-dangerous-inserted-yoast-message-in-page-headers?replies=29#post-2503475

I have found the class that adds the comment here: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/tags/1.2.8.7/frontend/class-frontend.php

Basically the `WPSEO_Frontend` class has a function named `debug_marker` which is then called by a function named `head` which is then added to `wp_head` in `__Construct`

I'm new to classes but I found a way to completely remove the head by doing

```
global $wpseo_front;    
remove_action( 'wp_head', array($wpseo_front,'head'), 1, 1 );
```

but I only want to remove the `debug_marker` part from it. I tried this but it dosen't work
`remove_action( 'wp_head', array($wpseo_front,'head','debug_marker'), 1, 1 );`

As I said I'm new to classes so any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this (but without the Class approach) is by filtering the output of `wp_head` action hook using the [output buffering](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

In your theme's `header.php`, wrap the `wp_head()` call with `ob_start($cb)` and `ob_end_flush();` functions like:

```
ob_start('ad_filter_wp_head_output');
wp_head();
ob_end_flush();
```

Now in theme `functions.php` file, declare your output callback function (`ad_filter_wp_head_output` in this case):

```
function ad_filter_wp_head_output($output) {
    if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {
        $output = str_ireplace('<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v' . WPSEO_VERSION . ' - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->', '', $output);
        $output = str_ireplace('<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->', '', $output);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

If you want to do all that through the `functions.php` without editing `header.php` file, you can hook to `get_header` and `wp_head` action hooks to define the output buffering session:

```
add_action('get_header', 'ad_ob_start');
add_action('wp_head', 'ad_ob_end_flush', 100);
function ad_ob_start() {
    ob_start('ad_filter_wp_head_output');
}
function ad_ob_end_flush() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
function ad_filter_wp_head_output($output) {
    if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {
        $output = str_ireplace('<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v' . WPSEO_VERSION . ' - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->', '', $output);
        $output = str_ireplace('<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->', '', $output);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I went with the hook method so I wouldn't have to edit header.php. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all your help, i finally resolved it.
I created a functions.php for my child theme, then add

```
// we get the instance of the class
$instance = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
/* then we remove the function
    You can remove also others functions, BUT remember that when you remove an action or a filter, arguments MUST MATCH with the add_action
    In our case, we had :
    add_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $this, 'debug_marker' ), 2 );

    so we do : 
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $this, 'debug_marker' ), 2 );
    */
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $instance, 'debug_marker' ), 2 );
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: If you can't get access to the class object, you can use my `remove_class_action` to remove the action/filter https://gist.github.com/tripflex/c6518efc1753cf2392559866b4bd1a53

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you are going to be able to do that using `remove_action`. The function argument in `remove_action` will not help you as the `debug_marker()` function was not the function that was used in the `add_action()` call.

Yoast presumably has something like `add_action( "wp_head", "head" )` in his code. So you can remove the "head" function, but `debug_marker` was not explicitly added as an action.

You could

1. Edit Yoast's source file and remove the debug comment line.
2. Extend the `WPSEO_Frontend` class and overload the `debug_marker` function to return "". TBH, I'm not sure how this would work in terms of WP loading the plugin, but could be worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks, I really don't want to edit the file. I would be interested in learning how to extend the class but this is a bit out of my knowledge.

Comment: Steve, I was trying solution 2 before bumping into your post. Although I was having problems completing this. I posted my progress as an answer in this page. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209800/84030 Your help would be appreciated if you have an idea how I could solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Finding this thread after working on the same solution as [the one mentioned by `Steve Claridge`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75140/84030), that is:

**Extend the `WPSEO_Frontend` class and overload the `debug_marker` function to return ""**

I detailed the steps below, although I'm getting stuck in the final step.

---

#### Create a customization plugin

As mentioned in [this article from WP Tavern](http://wptavern.com/how-to-extend-a-wordpress-plugin-without-losing-your-changes), "the easiest way to accomplish this is to create a functionality plugin that will run alongside it".

So I went on to [creating my first plugin following this article from ElegantTheme](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin).

#### Extend the relevant class.

That's when things got complicated. I added the following but my overriding function is still not triggered for some reason.

```
//get the base class
if(!class_exists('WPSEO_Frontend')) {
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-frontend.php';
}

/**
 * Class Definition
 */
class WPSEO_Frontend_GUP extends WPSEO_Frontend{

    /**
     * 
     * OVERRIDES function from YOAST SEO
     * 
     * Outputs or returns the debug marker, which is also used for title replacement when force rewrite is active.
     *
     * @param bool $echo Whether or not to echo the debug marker.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function debug_marker( $echo = true ) {
        return '';
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing this out! Yoast WordPress Seo has a bunch of actions and filters that allow us to do just partial changes to its classes, the class extend approach might help me a lot getting rid of some stuff on specific contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that you can remove the debug_marker action in functions.php.
Yoast plugin is executed in the wp_head action. I just took the action hook which follows directly after that, namely wp_enqueue_scripts and there I hooked a function that removed the debug_marker output. For this you also have to pass the plugin object. Also the priority number has to be the same as the one set from within the plugin.

```
function remove_debugmarker(){
global $wpseo_front;
remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array($wpseo_front, 'debug_marker') , 2 );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','remove_debugmarker');
```

However this does not remove the

```
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

part, because that is echoed in the plugin's crucial wrapper function *head*.
You could try overwriting that.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Ahmad's answer you could just remove all html comments with the same amount of code, since Yoast isn't the only plugin that does that.

```
   <?php
   function remove_html_comments_buffer_callback($buffer) {
        $buffer = preg_replace('/<!--[^\[\>\<](.|\s)*?-->/', '', $buffer);
        return $buffer;
    }
    function remove_html_comments_buffer_start() {
        ob_start("remove_html_comments_buffer_callback");
    }
    function remove_html_comments_buffer_end() {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_html_comments_buffer_start', -1);
    add_action('get_header', 'remove_html_comments_buffer_start'); 
    add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_html_comments_buffer_end', 999);
```

Comment: +1 for the generic approach. One might take a while to remove Yoast SEO comment to only discover there is another one coming up after installing another plugin.

Comment: Yea I hate when plugins do this. Yoast, revslider, w3 total cache and most other cache/minification plugins, and a ton others all do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across a snippet that removes all Yoast WordPress SEO comments from the front end. It also modifies the output buffering approach that @bryan-willis and @ahmad-m's answers use.

Simply place the snippet on your theme's `functions.php` or a custom plugin/theme php file.

***I'll leave it here as a reference - credit goes to the snippet's author***

```
/**
 * Yoast WordPress SEO Plugin - Remove All Yoast HTML Comments
 * See at: https://gist.github.com/paulcollett/4c81c4f6eb85334ba076
**/
if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')){
  add_action('get_header',function (){ ob_start(function ($o){
  return preg_replace('/\n?<.*?yoast.*?>/mi','',$o); }); });
  add_action('wp_head',function (){ ob_end_flush(); }, 999);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of @ahmad-m [Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75168/87737), by applying filters you can make multiple content changes to the header html .

```
function header_str_replace_start(){
    ob_start('header_str_replace_output');
}
function header_str_replace_output($output){
    return apply_filters('header_str_replace', $output);
}
function header_str_replace_finish(){
    ob_end_flush();
}
add_action('get_header', 'header_str_replace_start',-1);
add_action('wp_head', 'header_str_replace_finish', 999);


add_filter( 'header_str_replace', 'remove_yeost_seo_comments' ) ;
add_filter( 'header_str_replace', 'remove_white_space');


function remove_yeost_seo_comments($output) {
    $output = str_ireplace('<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->', '', $output);
    return $output;
}


function remove_white_space($content){
     return trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $content));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar solution for `functions.php` which does not use hardcoded priority `2` but dynamically reads and uses the priority from Yoast `add_action()`.

```
// disable 'This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO ...'
if ( class_exists( 'WPSEO_Frontend') && method_exists( 'WPSEO_Frontend', 'get_instance' ) ) {
    $wpseo_front = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
    if ( $wpseo_dbg_prio = has_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $wpseo_front, 'debug_mark' ) ) ) {
        remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $wpseo_front, 'debug_mark'), $wpseo_dbg_prio );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

See flush_cache function in wordpress-seo/frontend/class-frontend.php

Find this line of code

```
$content = str_replace( $this->debug_marker( false ), $this->debug_marker( false ) . "\n" . '<title>' . $title . '</title>', $content );
```

Replace with

```
$content = str_replace( $this->debug_marker( false ), '<title>' . $title . '</title>', $content );
```

Thanks to the creator of this great plugin.

Comment: Never change any file in any theme, plugin or core if you are not the author. Also, please do not use this site for promotional reasons.

Comment: Sorry, Im not make a promotion. I just provide another solution. Perhaps not the best.

Comment: *consider make a donation* is promotion, you either benefit directly or indirectly from this finansialy