# How to stop or remove an action being called inside a function of an extended class

Tags: plugins, php, functions, actions, the-events-calendar

### The Problem

I am trying to remove an JSON+LD block being added by a WordPress plugin called The Events Calendar.

I believe it is being added by the function called: `Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event` within which the function named `google_data_markup` is responsible for the actual markup which I am trying to stop/prevent from being added to the HTML.

### The Code

From my limited understanding of this, I need to remove this action:

> `add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'google_data_markup' ) );`.

I believe it is being called here, in Single_Event.php:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event' ) ) {
    /**
     * Single event template class
     */
    class Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event extends Tribe__Events__Template_Factory {

        protected $body_class = 'events-single';

        public function hooks() {
            parent::hooks();

            // google data markup
            add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'google_data_markup' ) );

        }

        public function google_data_markup() {
            $event_markup = new Tribe__Events__Google_Data_Markup__Event();
            $html = apply_filters( 'tribe_google_data_markup_json', $event_markup->script_block() );
            echo $html;
        }

        /**
        ...
```

---

### What I've tried

#### Initial Attempts

After finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356365/need-help-removing-action-from-plugin-file) on StackOverflow, and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96300/removing-an-action-from-an-external-plugin-class) on WordPress Dev Exchange, I tried:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( 'Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event', 'google_data_markup' ) );
```

and

```
global $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event;
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event, 'google_data_markup' ) );
```

But it did not work.

#### Subsequent Attempts

After getting even more desperate and seeing [this slim thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924427/how-to-remove-an-action-added-through-a-class) (the example in that thread seems very similar to mine but no answer provided that I understand), and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/remove-an-action-from-an-external-class), I've also tried this, with the `&` before the variable name (why?):

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( &$Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event, 'google_data_markup' ) );
```

I've also tried this:

```
function remove_the_events_calendar_jsonld() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event, 'google_data_markup' ) );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_the_events_calendar_jsonld', 1 );
```

as well as:

```
remove_action( 'Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event', 'google_data_markup' );
```

Please help.  At this point I have no idea if I am making a simple syntax or logic error of sorts, or if I am completely confused and oblivious to how functions, classes and actions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with help from an SO user!

This will remove the `ld+json` block added by *The Events Calendar*:

```
add_filter( 'tribe_google_data_markup_json', '__return_empty_string', 20 );
```