# How to control initial wp_head() output?

Tags: theme-development, wp-head

I followed the common advise to use wp_head() in header.php and wp_enqueue_scripts() instead of hard linking css and js files in header.php.

However, I realized that wp_head() outputs lots of stuff I'm not sure if I really want it to be there. E.g. there is some CSS stylesheet stuff dealing with emotiis and smileys ... for whatever reason.

//UPDATE

Despite my writing above, I am pretty aware of what parts of wp_head() I want to have in my HTML Head section.

//UPDATE II

I am developing my own theme and I have only a single plugin in use which is Pods.io.

I did some research but found solutions only that suggest to subsequently alter wp_head() output via output buffering methods (see [Remove an action from an external Class](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/remove-an-action-from-an-external-class/75168#75168)). To me, that appears to be a rather dirty solution.

Hence, my question is, how can I exactly define the default output of wp_head()? What hooks are available to trigger certain output parts? Pls note, I am aware of how to *add* content to wp_head() via hooks but not how to *precisely remove* unwanted output.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/9fb5c540bb7888faec05670bd70a93e0593dcfb1/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L224) is everything hooked to `wp_head`. Also, check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/185577/31545) on how to remove emojicons

Comment: @PieterGoosen: Cool, so with that information I can simply remove certain default actions, am I right?

E.g. `remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_styles');`

Comment: That is correct. Just make sure, actions needs to be removed with the same priority which was used when they were added

Comment: Fine. Allright, got it. If you'd reply this as an answer, I could mark the question solved by your answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/9fb5c540bb7888faec05670bd70a93e0593dcfb1/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L224) is the current list of actions that is currently hooked by default to `wp_head`

Reposted here to avoid unnecessary opening multiple browser windows

```
add_action( 'wp_head',             '_wp_render_title_tag',            1     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_enqueue_scripts',              1     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'feed_links',                      2     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'feed_links_extra',                3     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'rsd_link'                               );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wlwmanifest_link'                       );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'locale_stylesheet'                      );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'noindex',                          1    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'print_emoji_detection_script',     7    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_print_styles',                  8    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_print_head_scripts',            9    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_generator'                           );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'rel_canonical'                          );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_shortlink_wp_head',            10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_site_icon',                    99    );

if ( isset( $_GET['replytocom'] ) )
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_no_robots' );
```

You can remove any action with [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_styles, 8 );
```

Just remember, an action need to be removed with the same priority it was added.

As bonus, check [this epic post from @ChristineCooper](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/185577/31545) on how to remove emojicons

### EDIT

An important note here. The foillowing actions should not be removed as this causes serious issues with how stylesheets and scripts are loaded

- `locate_stylesheet`
- `wp_print_styles`
- `wp_generator`
- `wp_enqueue_scripts`

If you need something specific removed, rather remove the call back function with `remove_action` or use the specific functions allocated to remove styles and scripts

Answer (score 0):

The wp_head hook is simply a hook.

Themes and plugins use this hook to add stuff they need in the header, like css and js. Very often they enqueue unnecessary scripts in every page instead of limiting them in specific pages.

So you can either check your plugins and theme where it enques the scripts and edit them or use the remove_action to remove them.

Comment: *In some rare occasions perhaps* Not true and not supported by any facts. More than often plugin and theme authors hook a bunch of unnecessary crap to `wp_head`. If you look at a few questions here, even commercial themes and plugins **AND** core have unnecessary stuff clotting up `wp_head`. Would be nice to know where you get your info from

Comment: You are right, I changed it to "very often".

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to remove default WordPress styles (which are included from wp-includes, they are all there for some reasons).

You can remove styles which are included from theme by creating child theme.

Comment: *You are not suppose to remove default WordPress styles*) WHY NOT??? That is the purpose of actions and filters in the first place, to remove/modify/add to core features as you see fit

Comment: because they are there for some reason... i.e. **admin-bar.min.css** is for displaying admin header if user is logged in. I mean you should not remove default styles and js, If you want to do so then go for core PHP instead

Comment: And if don't like the way admin header is displayed...?

Comment: There are functions for that too...try `<?php show_admin_bar( $bool ); ?>` removing css won't remove header.

Comment: @MayurChauhan: I am very aware of what parts of the default WP core wp_head() output I'd like to remove. Maybe, my original writing was a bit sloppy at this part. I am looking for a proper way to remove parts I really don't want to be there.

Comment: I know you're(@PieterGoosen) guy with 27627 repo... you might(will) be better than me... but this is what I think.....

Comment: My reputation has got nothing to do with this ;-). Anything can be removed from core if there is a filter or action provided for it, so can anything be added or modified through the appropriate hook. Whether something will be save to modify depend on the usecase and how the modification is implemented. What you should never ever do is to remove/add/modify something directly in a core file, that is bad, and that should be something that you should not do.

Comment: Ya totaly agree.. perfect

Comment: @PieterGoosen Now that I read all the comments of yours, it all makes sense. Sorry for being stubborn :p

Comment: if you are supposed to securize your custom theme, and you do not want all the crap generator, canonical etc... tags in your head, then this might be a good question