# How to remove WPML Generator Meta Tag by theme's functions.php (override plugin function)?

Tags: plugins, functions, plugin-wpml

I've tried hard to find a way to not let plugin [WPML](http://wpml.org/) output the following `<meta name="generator" content="WPML ver:2.8.1 stt:3,1;0" />` tag in `<head>` via help of theme's `function.php`:

It's called in `sitepress.class.php` beginning with line 255

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'meta_generator_tag' ) );
}
```

This specific question has already been asked once in [WPML forum](http://wpml.org/forums/topic/removing-wpml-version-meta-tag-from-header/).
I've tried:

```
/* ::: Disable WPML Meta Generator Tag ::: */
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'meta_generator_tag', 20 );
}
add_filter( 'meta_generator_tag', 'theme_generator_tag' );

function theme_generator_tag() {
    return false;
}
```

-- without success

Comment: Should be closed. We can't look at the plugins source or test anything.

Comment: Possibly a [DUPLICATE OF THIS QUESTION](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes) - read answer to see the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The instance of this class is made global by WPML, so this should work:

```
if ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['sitepress'] ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_head', function()
    {
        remove_action(
            current_filter(),
            array ( $GLOBALS['sitepress'], 'meta_generator_tag' )
        );
    },
    0
    );
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work on my server, it works locally for me though.
Facing WP 3.6.1 on PHP 5.2.6-1 on the server and on PHP 5.3 locally. 

Getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION` back`.

Comment: Is your server’s PHP version up to date? It should be at least version 5.4.

Comment: You're amazingly fast ;)

Comment: Is there a way to get this working in PHP 5.2.x?

Comment: Yes, create a named function and use that as callback. But why would you stay with an [insecure](http://www.cvedetails.com/version/106044/PHP-PHP-5.2.17.html), slow and outdated PHP version?

Comment: Well, I've been able to finally get rid of it by including `remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $sitepress, 'meta_generator_tag', 20 ) );` in functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note different `remove_action()`:

```
if(!is_admin()){
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array($sitepress, 'meta_generator_tag') );
}
add_filter( 'meta_generator_tag', 'theme_generator_tag' );

function theme_generator_tag() {
    return false;
}
```

It worked for versions 2.0.4.1 and before, but not tested for newer ones.

Comment: Thanks for your input. First I thought it should be the array notation as well. But it doesn't work. :\

Comment: I've found an old theme of mine where just one line was used in `functions.php`: `remove_action( 'wp_head', array($sitepress, 'meta_generator_tag' ) );`.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't make to much difference. For me as administrator, I obviously should know which version of WPML I'm using.
Still, it doesn't work. I also put in the add_filter to ensure meta_generator_tag isn't used. Could it be that it's not possible to override the function via theme's function.php (anymore, as of 2.8.1)?

Comment: The last idea is to add `global $sitepress;` before the code above.