# Remove_action from plugin with a Class

Tags: plugins, actions

I've searched around but haven't been able to find a solution to this. I'm trying to hook in and remove an action that was initiated by a plugin (specifically the Groups plugin). The function itself is contained within a class in the plugin. It basically breaks down like this

```
class Groups_Registered {
...
    public static function init() {
       add_action( 'user_register', array( __CLASS__, 'user_register' ) );
    }
...
}
Groups_Registered::init();
```

I've tried to just remove the action, referring back to the class, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've added this to my functions.php file, but it is not removing the action. A

```
remove_action( 'user_register', array( Groups_Registered::init(), 'user_register' ) );
```

Anyone know how to solve? I've seen some solutions out there but none of them seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove\_action or remove\_filter with external classes?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes)

Comment: @MarkKaplun that doesn't appear to work. I think because the Groups_Registered class is not actually initiated or set in a variable?

Comment: what doesn't appear to work? there are several methods in those answers.

Comment: @MarkKaplun well, any of them. I tried:
`function mfields_test_remove_actions() {
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_wp_footer' );
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', array( 'MyClass', 'my_action' ), 10 );
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', array( 'MyStaticClass', 'my_action' ), 10 );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mfields_test_remove_actions' );`
with user_register and the Groups_Registered class, but that didn't do it.

Comment: How are you verifying the action status?  In other words, how do you know your attempts are not working?

Comment: @jdm2112 the hook itself adds a user to the "Registered" group whenever a new user is created. I've been creating users every time I try something to see if that behavior continues. If I remove that line of code from the plugin itself, this behavior stops.

Comment: @JasonHoffmann, are you sure that you call the remove after the hook was added but before it is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just match the callback in your remove call - `array( CLASSNAME, METHOD )`:

```
remove_action( 'user_register', array( 'Groups_Registered', 'user_register' ) );
```