# Global Objects and Public Methods

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, globals

I'm developing a plugin and am just thinking over best practices. How common is it to have a global object? Currently on `plugins_loaded` I am creating a global object of my class:

```php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Test_Plugin', 'init' ) );
...
public static function init() {
    global $testerski;
    $testerski = __CLASS__;
    $testerski = new $testerski;
}
```

This allows me to use the `global $testerski` to call any variables or methods. Is this a common practice?

---

My other concern is that since I am creating a global object and from my understanding, any hooks have to have public functions so WordPress can call them. The problem is that I can call these functions meant for hooks from my global object. For example, I have some hooks registered as:

```php
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init',             array( $this, 'test_plugin_setup' )             );
    add_action( 'template_include', array( $this, 'test_templates' )                );
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules',   array( $this, 'test_add_monthly_schedule' )     ); 
}

public function test_templates( $template ) {
    ...
}
```

Which I *could* technically call using `$testerski->test_templates()`. Since this function shouldn't really be called directly and only used for hooks - is there a way I can prevent it from being called directly like this? Is something like this dangerous or am I overthinking it?

I've noticed some hooks have warnings, like `wp_enqueue_scripts` will give you a notice that it was called incorrectly.

Comment: I'm just wondering, it might be a good idea to submit your full code to [codereview.se] as well. I got a couple of really good suggestions regarding OOP and classes there which helped me a lot ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I posted a [question here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117978/7063).

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Did you see [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36110/46066) from Otto?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not common practice, but it works. A better approach, is to use a class and with the singleton pattern, just like WooCommerce and many others, where you have:

- A static function (called `instance`, `getInstance`...) that:

  - Creates an instance (object) if not already done and returns it
  - **Or** returns the existing instance

Let's continue with the WooCommerce example; we used to do this to access the global object:

```php
global $woocommerce;
```

Now we do:

```php
WooCommerce::instance();

# Or with the handy Shortcut
WC();
```

I think you will enjoy reading these:

- WooCommerce::instance() https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-WC.html#104-119
- https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-WC.html#524-534
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

---

You can check the value of `current_filter()` inside your method, but if I were you, I wouldn't bother. This is not a threat, and other developers may want to use your code, so don't block them.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know a ton of OOP and Singletons are new to me so it's a cool concept. I do find it funny that the wiki references are commenting on how bad Singletons are but they also say that globals are bad so I'll take it with a grain of salt. I also have a similar [question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117978/7063) if you wanna get points there too :)