# Remove action from woocommerce barcode plugin

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, order

i'm trying to make some changes to the woocommerce barcode plugin. I want to remove this action from the plugin class-woocommerce-order-barcodes.php:

```
class WooCommerce_Order_Barcodes {
...
public function __construct ( $file = '', $version = '1.0.0' ) {
...
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', array( $this, 'get_display_barcode' ), 1, 1 );
...
}
}
```

The reason why i want to remove is because i already have the barcode snippet in another place (inside a tidy DIV in my order-detail.php child template) and the one inserted by the plugin automatically is repeated below (see image)
[Woocommerce order barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0e1U.jpg). The custom code inside the template is this one

```
<div class="barcode">
    <?php echo WC_Order_Barcodes()->display_barcode($order_id);?>
</div>
```

If course if a remove manually the add_action from the plugin class, i get the result that i want, but i don't want to modify the plugin files.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: the article from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013) did not resolve my problem, i use the code below and it didn't solve the problem =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove\_action or remove\_filter with external classes?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes)

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the class variable to remove a action which has been added within a class

```
function remove_default_order_barcode(){
   global $WooCommerce_Order_Barcodes ;
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', array( $WooCommerce_Order_Barcodes, 'get_display_barcode' ), 1, 1 );

}
 add_action('init','remove_default_order_barcode');
```

hope it will help you  !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didn't work, still have the default barcode below. Do you need the complete code? I can post the php file. It's 900 lines of code.

Comment: This is the file class-woocommerce-order-barcodes.php. http://pastebin.com/q5GJ0Mdr

Comment: thanks for sharing code @chenci. I think  [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes) can help you to understand it better.

Comment: thank you i will see to it. It's weird, the code you gave me, it should work. Is there a wordpress debug where you can see the code executing behind?

Comment: After reading the article still with no clear answer in this problem