# Remove action added in plugin class from theme

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, filters, actions

I am trying to remove action that is added via plugin in my theme. The below plugin class creates a portfolio page template but I don't want this page template in my theme. Is there any way to unhook or remove it?

Below is the plugin class:

```
class Raratheme_Companion_Templates
    {
        function init()
        {
            add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'rrtc_include_template_function' ) );
            add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'rrtc_add_portfolio_templates' ) );
        }
        /**
         * Portfolio template.
        */
        function rrtc_get_portfolio_template( $template ) {
            $post = get_post();
            $page_template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
            if( $page_template == 'templates/portfolio.php' ){
                if ( $theme_file = locate_template( 'templates/portfolio.php' ) ) {
                    return $theme_file;
                } else {
                    return RARATC_BASE_PATH . '/includes/templates/portfolio.php';
                }
            }
            return $template;
        }

        /**
         * Template over-ride for single portfolio.
         *
         * @since    1.0.0
         */
        function rrtc_include_template_function( $template_path ) {
            if ( get_post_type() == 'rara-portfolio' ) {
                if ( is_single() ) {
                    if ( $theme_file = locate_template( 'single-rara-portfolio.php' ) ) {
                        $template_path = $theme_file;
                    } else {
                        $template_path = RARATC_BASE_PATH . '/includes/templates/single-rara-portfolio.php';
                    }
                }
            }
            return $template_path;
        }


        /**
         * Portfolio template returned.
        */
        function rrtc_filter_admin_page_templates( $templates ) {
            $templates['templates/portfolio.php'] = __( 'Portfolio Template', 'raratheme-companion' );
            return $templates;
        }

        /**
         * Portfolio template added.
        */
        function rrtc_add_portfolio_templates() {
            if( is_admin() ) {
                add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', array($this, 'rrtc_filter_admin_page_templates' ) );
            }
            else {
                add_filter( 'page_template', array( $this, 'rrtc_get_portfolio_template' ) );
            }
        }
    }
    $obj = new Raratheme_Companion_Templates;
    $obj->init();
```

I tried this with no success:

```
function def()
{
    // global $obj;
    // $obj = new Raratheme_Companion_Templates;
    if( is_admin() ) {
        remove_filter( 'theme_page_templates', array('Raratheme_Companion_Templates', 'rrtc_filter_admin_page_templates' ) );
    }
    else {
        remove_filter( 'page_template', array( 'Raratheme_Companion_Templates', 'rrtc_get_portfolio_template' ) );
    }
    // echo "test";
    // wp_die();
    // $plugin_admin = new Raratheme_Companion_Admin();
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'Raratheme_Companion_Templates', 'rrtc_add_portfolio_templates' ) );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','def',10000);
```

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is `$obj = new Raratheme_Companion_Templates; $obj->init();` placed? Inside a called action/another function? If you do `global $obj;` do you get the created object of class `Raratheme_Companion_Templates`?

Comment: The class `Raratheme_Companion_Templates` is from the plugin and yes `$obj = new Raratheme_Companion_Templates; $obj->init();` is in the plugin class. And I tried using `global $obj` but couldn't get it done.

Comment: Can you post the full file where this code is in? Also check out [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239431) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/289426) answer, these will probably be the last resort solution

Comment: I have already added the whole plugin file above. The first block of code with `Raratheme_Companion_Templates` class is the plugin class. And below is what I tried. I am trying to remove the page template added by plugin class from actions and filters in the child theme.

Comment: Ok, then you'll have to use a method as describe in the two answers I linked. You **cannot** use standard methods, because of object orientation and `$obj` being unavailable (not suprising with such a generic name)