# Remove an action by extending class and replacing it

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks, oop

I'm trying to override a method (`my_packages`) from the `WP Job Manager Paid Listings` plugin by extending it's class from within a custom plugin

Here is how the source code (none-related code removed) is set up...

```
class WC_Paid_Listings_Orders {

  private static $instance;

  public static function get_instance() {

      return null === self::$instance ? ( self::$instance = new self ) : self::$instance;
  }

  public function __construct() {

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( $this, 'my_packages' ) );

  }

  public function my_packages() {

    // This is what I want to unhook

  }

}
```

How would I 'unhook' `my_packages`? This is what I have thus far (and failing with)! I'm guessing it's to do with the instance? I've tries all sorts of iterations from examples on here but to no avail - Operating at the edge of my knowledge here I'm afraid.

```
class cvl_override_defaults extends WC_Paid_Listings_Orders {

   public function __construct() {

    remove_action('woocommerce_before_my_account', array( $this, 'my_packages'));

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', array( $this, 'new_my_packages' ) );

   }

   public function new_my_packages() {

     // New output goes in here

   }

}
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in this line:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_my_account', array( $this, 'my_packages'));
```

This won't remove action registered by parent class, because `$this` is a different object in this case, so you won't remove any action at all.

So how to remove such action? Since you can't access the same `$this` value in your class, you'll have to iterate through all filters and remove the given one manually.

Here's a good example how to do that:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239431/34172

Comment: Thank you - I thought it may be something to do with this after some further reading.

Working!!! :D

Comment: `WC_Paid_Listings_Orders` has a method for getting the instance of the class, so iterating through filters manually shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

When an action is added using a specific instance of a class (when you see `$this`), to remove the action you need to pass the *same instance* of the class to `remove_action()`.

Since `WC_Paid_Listings_Orders` is a Singleton (it appears), there is only one instance of the class, and you can get that instance using the `get_instance()` method. You can then use that instance to remove the action.

```
$wc_paid_listings_orders = WC_Paid_Listings_Orders::get_instance();
remove_action( $wc_paid_listings_orders, 'my_packages' );
```

Comment: As long as it's singleton this should work just fine, otherwise will need to use my class action remove functions https://gist.github.com/tripflex/c6518efc1753cf2392559866b4bd1a53