# Remove action hook from Class, understanding OOP

Tags: functions, actions

I am trying to remove an action that is within a class, of the parent theme. I made an example of the code I have, below. I am trying to remove the action in the child theme functions.php. I've tried multiple solutions, including defining the class into a variable like: `$my_class = new My_Widget();` (that needs to be done for static functions?), but I can't find a good solution. Who can help me further understand this?

**parent theme file**

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct( $args = array() ) {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact_owner', array( __CLASS__, 'contact_process' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_owner', array( __CLASS__, 'contact_process' ) );

    }

    public static function contact_process() {
        global $cc_options;         
        echo 'test';
    }

}
```

**functions.php child theme**

```
function cc_remove_action(){    
    remove_action( 'wp_ajax_contact_owner', array('My_Widget', 'contact_process' ), 11 );
    remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_owner', array( 'My_Widget', 'contact_process' ), 11 );
}   
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cc_remove_action' );
```

Comment: please  use this action : add_action('init','cc_remove_action');

Comment: Tried that, but still not working.

Comment: please check url :https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes

Comment: also check : https://inpsyde.com/en/remove-wordpress-hooks/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove\_action or remove\_filter with external classes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes)

Comment: Doing something like `add_action( 'some_class_init', function( SomeClass $some_class ) {
  remove_action( 'on_init', [ $some_class, 'on_init' ] );
} );` seems to unhook it, but i really don't know what I am doing here and if I am not breaking other functions