# Removing Plugin Action via Theme for Non-admins

Tags: plugins, themes, actions

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'mytheme_remove_show_my_balance' );
function mytheme_remove_show_my_balance() {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'personal_options', array( $this, 'show_my_balance' ) );
  }
}
```

The above is what I've tried and the following two files in the plugin contain the action that I wish to remove or otherwise block or disable:

https://github.com/mycred/myCRED/blob/master/includes/mycred-admin.php

https://github.com/mycred/myCRED/blob/master/modules/mycred-module-management.php

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, perhaps helps it when you add `global $your_class_name;` inside the function to get access to the class object instance at all. And replacing `$this` also with $your_class_name?

Comment: Welcome to the community. When using `remove_action()` to remove a hooked method of an instance of a class ($this), you should get that instance first!
See this: [remove_action or remove_filter with external classes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239431/146615)