# remove_action returns false regardless of priority

Tags: actions

I am writing my own plugin to customize a public plugin. My plugin is doing this customization by removing an action via remove_action() and adding it back with my customized code. The code below illustrates just the removal part in a testable way. Obviously both plugins need to be active to illustrate the problem.

**First, the original plugin:**

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Sample_Plugin
  Version: 1.0.0
 * 
 */

class Sample_Plugin {
    function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'admin_init'));
    }

    public function admin_init() {
        add_action('admin_head', array($this, 'js_vars'));
    }

    public function js_vars() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // AJAX link used for the autosuggest
            var sample_ajax_suggest_link = <?php
        echo wp_json_encode(
                add_query_arg(
                        array(
                            'action' => 'sample_ajax_suggest',
                            'post_type' => rawurlencode(get_post_type()),
                        ),
                        wp_nonce_url('admin-ajax.php', 'sample-plugin')
                )
        );
        ?>;
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}    
global $sample_plugin;
$sample_plugin = new Sample_Plugin();
```

**My plugin to modify the plugin above:**

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: CUSTOMIZE the Sample_Plugin
  Version: 1.0.0
 * 
 */

global $sample_plugin;

$result = remove_action('admin_head', array($sample_plugin, 'js_vars'));

if($result){
    $result = "Yes, it was.";
}else{
    $result = "No, it wasn't.";
}
error_log("Was the action removed? " . $result);
```

**Why is remove_action in the "CUSTOMIZE" plugin returning false**? I've tried changing the priority but I get the same result.

Comment: Are you certain that the sample plugin is instantiated into the global namespace into that exact variable? Many plugin classes instantiate anonymously. Have you tried this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239431/7355