# Removing filters with arguments set in a class

Tags: plugins, filters

I'm using a plugin (The Events Calendar) and I need to remove a specific filter set within plugin's class.

```
class Hooks extends \tad_DI52_ServiceProvider {
    ...
    add_filter( 'posts_pre_query', [ $this, 'filter_posts_pre_query' ], 20, 2 );
    ...
```

Using

```
remove_filter( 'posts_pre_query', 'Hooks::filter_posts_pre_query', 20 );
```

or

```
remove_filter( 'posts_pre_query', [ 'Hooks', 'filter_posts_pre_query' ], 20 );
```

set in functions.php file of a theme does not help.

Calling remove_all_filters() in functions.php does work but I need to remove only that specific filter, so this won't cut it for me.
There is also no static or singleton instance of 'Hooks' class, so I cannot use it in remove_filter() function call.

How can I remove this filter without modifying plugin's files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove\_action or remove\_filter with external classes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes) Otto’s answer is the most relevant.

Comment: you need a reference to `$this`/the object that the hook is in to remove it, you can't use static strings unless it's a static method. How you get a reference to that object though is something you need to ask in an Events Calendar community as it depends on how the plugin is built and you can't ask about 3rd party plugins here

Comment: @JacobPeattie No, unfortunately Otto's answer does not help, since I cannot access an instance of an object as it located in a private property of a class.

Comment: @DmitriiIlchenko if you can't get access to the object then it may not be possible to reliably and easily do this without modifying the plugin itself